# How to save record in DB as text not as id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing meal ordering system, I'm new in Rails and I'm wondering how can I save record (ordered meal from restaurant) in the DB as text. For example I have a list of restaurants and meals in my *db/seed.rb* and when I order a meal from the restaurant in my order view intead of see ordered meal (name of the meal and name of the restaurant) I see id of restaurant and id of meal. I know it's probobly easy to fix, but I have no idea go to do this.

```
db/seed.rb

 Restaurant.create(name: "PizzaHut")
 Restaurant.create(name: "Salad Story")
 Restaurant.create(name: "KFC")

 Meal.create(name: "PizzaHut Special - 32cm", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "PizzaHut").id)
 Meal.create(name: "PizzaHut Special - 42cm", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "PizzaHut").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Pepperoni - 32cm", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "PizzaHut").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Pepperoni - 42cm", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "PizzaHut").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Hawaii - 32cm", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "PizzaHut").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Hawaii - 42cm", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "PizzaHut").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Diablo - 32cm", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "PizzaHut").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Diablo - 42cm", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "PizzaHut").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Longer + Small Drink (Coca-Cola, Fanta, Sprite)", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "KFC").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Longer + Large Drink (Coca-Cola, Fanta, Sprite)", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "KFC").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Greek Salad - Medium", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "Salad Story").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Greek Salad - Large", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "Salad Story").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Salad Story Special - Medium", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "Salad Story").id)
 Meal.create(name: "Salad Story Special - Large", restaurant_id: Restaurant.find_by(name: "Salad Story").id)
```

`staticpages/home.html.erb`

```
 <h1 class="jumbotron-font">Order your meal</h1>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
         <%= form_for(:orders, url: new_order_path) do |f| %>

           <%= f.label :restaurant, "Restaurant" %>
           <%= f.collection_select :restaurant_id, Restaurant.order(:name), :id,
          :name, {prompt: "Select a restaurant"}, {class: "form-control"} %>

           <%= f.label :meal, "Choose your meal" %>
           <%= f.grouped_collection_select :meal_id, Restaurant.order(:name),
            :meals, :name, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a meal"},
                                                  {class: "form-control"} %>

           <%= f.label :suggestions, "Suggestions" %>
           <%= f.text_area :suggestions, rows: "4", placeholder: "e.g. I'd like to change sweetcorn for olives..." %>

           <%= f.submit "Place your order", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
         <% end %>
       </div>
     </div>
```

And `db/schema.rb`

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161220125950) do

   create_table "meals", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string   "name"
     t.integer  "restaurant_id"
     t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
     t.index ["restaurant_id"], name: "index_meals_on_restaurant_id"
   end

   create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string   "restaurant"
     t.string   "meal"
     t.text     "suggestions"
     t.integer  "user_id"
     t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
     t.string   "restaurant_id"
     t.string   "meal_id"
     t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id_and_created_at"
     t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id"
   end

   create_table "restaurants", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string   "name"
     t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
   end

   create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
     t.string   "provider"
     t.string   "uid"
     t.string   "name"
     t.datetime "created_at", null: false
     t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   end

 end
```

My logs:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TVdB/YJ8W2fQD0XslA7KwlY2WHPPTSsI6Tx18CE1v6vF9zJLjM5nFd6lO/gSrPwsy/fCnra54TeAtxrwGyIGoQ==", "orders"=>{"restaurant_id"=>"1", "meal_id"=>"11", "suggestions"=>""}, "commit"=>"Place your order"}
   User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   Restaurant Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants" WHERE "restaurants"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   SQL (91.1ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("suggestions", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "restaurant_id", "meal_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["suggestions", ""], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", 2016-12-20 14:05:13 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-12-20 14:05:13 UTC], ["restaurant_id", "1"], ["meal_id", "11"]]
    (241.2ms)  commit transaction
```

*** UPDATE ***

```
 class Order < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :restaurant
 end

 class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :orders
   has_many :restaurants, through: :orders
 end

 class Meal < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :restaurant
 end

 class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :orders
   has_many :meals
   has_many :users, through: :orders
 end
```

From view I have just `order/index.html.erb`

```
 <% @orders.each do |order| %>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
       <%= order.restaurant_name %>
       <%= order.meal_name %>
       <%= order.suggestions %>
     </div>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

It's simple application, just for practice, so I want to do single page application without actually confirming the order by restaurant. I want to be able to make the order and then see in history list of all orders.

Comment: You should be able to access that data if you are getting the id if the proper associations are set up.  could you post the view and models code for meal order and restaurant?  you probably do not need the schema.rb code as well as the form, logs or seeds.

Comment: @RockwellRice thanks, I updated my answer

Comment: @RockwellRice I did like you said and now I get an error SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: meals.order_id: SELECT "meals".* FROM "meals" WHERE "meals"."order_id" = ? LIMIT ?

Answer (score 0):

I generally use f.association for select fields.
If the problem is in your form, in the select field (on the home page) then try:

```
<%= f.label :restaurant, "Restaurant" %>
       <%= f.association :restaurants, collection: Restaurant.order(:name), {prompt: "Select a restaurant"}, {class: "form-control"} %>

       <%= f.label :meal, "Choose your meal" %>
       <%= f.association :meals, collection: Restaurant.order(:name).meals, {prompt: "Select a meal"},
                                              {class: "form-control"} %>
```

That or using the .pluck method to say that you specifically want to show the name:

```
Restaurant.order(:name).pluck(:name)
```